# python timer for periodic tracing without sleep

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I am new to python, I want to trace after 10 sec, however without sleeping in poll.

Is there a way in python to specify `t = time.add(hr)` and then check `time.now < t` ?

start a process using `subprocess.popen`

```
while poll is None && time < 1 hr 
read line available on stdout and stderr
on every 10 sec 
trace something
```

Comment: If you are on Unix, you can use [`signal.setitimer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer).

Answer (score 0):

You can call recursively the method in the Thread

```
import time, threading
def foo():
   print(time.ctime())
   threading.Timer(10, foo).start()
```

and when you call it:

> foo()
>
> Sat Feb 27 14:46:08 2016
>
> Sat Feb 27 14:46:18 2016
>
> Sat Feb 27 14:46:28 2016
>
> Sat Feb 27 14:46:38 2016